# How to capture error message from third-party-library in Lua?

Tags: json, lua, ierrorhandler

I have adopted the [LuaJSON](http://luaforge.net/projects/luajson/) to parse JSON. The parse call seems like that:

```
-- file.lua
local res = json.decode.decode(json_str)
if res == nil then
    throw('invalid JSON')
end
...
```

But if the `json_str` is badly formated, the `decode()` will stop within LuaJSON and interrupt the execution of *file.lua*. I want the control flow to return to my function instead, so I can provide a custom error notification.

I have browsed the LuaJSON APIs, and there is no *callback-like* error handling. I want to know is there any Lua mechanism that allows me to handle errors occuring within LuaJSON from within *file.lua*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that the `decode` function calls [`error`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-error) if it encounters an error.

This is Lua's equivalent to an exception handling mechanism. What you want to do is call the `decode` function in [protected mode](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.3):

```
local success, res = pcall(json.decode.decode, json_str);
if success then
    -- res contains a valid json object
    ...
else
    -- res contains the error message
    ...
end
```

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff That depends on the interface of the `decode` call. I was just trying to illustrate the use of `pcall`.

Comment: IMO, the line `if res == nil then` in the question is pretty clear about this feature of `decode` call.

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff Yes, but that code assumed `decode` to return normally in the failure case (i.e. not via a longjmp triggered by `error`), which clearly it does not.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, if you are using CJSON version 2.1.0, there is a new "cjson.safe" module, which will return nil and error msg if any exception occurred in encode or decode procedure.

```
local decoder = require("cjson.safe").decode
local decoded_data, err = decoder(data)
if err then
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Invalid request payload:", data)
    ngx.exit(400)
end
```